# How to get list of tape devices in Windows

Tags: c++, c

I have been looking around how to work with tapes in windows. The few samples I've seen open the tape device using "\\.\TAPE0" but never show how to get that name. I think trying to open files to check the available devices (TAPE0 to TAPE(N)) is a horrible idea, there must be a better way. So, is there a way to list the tape devices in windows?

Comment: Has there been a time-slip back to the 80's?